# Best algorithm to resolve a tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, service

I have a JSON dataset, published from a CMS, which contains a mixture of attributes and "references to content".  The resolution of the references is currently done by recursion, via a HTTP request, which looks up the ID and injects the response.  There may then be further references in the response so the recursion depth can be quite high (up to 20 levels).  The dataset is extremely granular, by requirement, stored in a document database, which probably isn't the best choice.

The effect of runtime, is basically a DDOS effect, as might be expected.  The algorithm can take up to 3 minutes; at worst, it 503's the service.

Attached a rubbish picture of what it looks like, to help.[image]

I'm pretty hopeless with algorithmic complexity, so forgive me, but I'm pretty sure this is O(2^n) time complexity, so pretty unscalable beyond trivial tree height?

I'm looking for obvious ways to optimise this first run, other than memoisation in the resolution service.  The only way I can see is either compose the document up front, which is against the client wishes as they want to avoid lengthy publishing times, or do something at the database level with a "View" with a TTL, which would be eventually consistent.

Comment: Which language are you using for parsing ? Are you sure there isn't a public JSON library for this language ? It should be optimized...

Comment: I don't think that this is an algorithmic problem. It's the size of the data itself. In general you could even have duplicated subtrees (if a reference is used more than once) or infinite recursion in case of cyclic references. I suggest to reconsider if full resolution of the tree is really necessary.

Comment: Hi, Martin - Node JS, and Couchbase is the DB.  The issue I'm facing isn't the JSON parsing or composition, it's the requirement to use recursion, as the dataset is totally fragmented, and the services are stateless.

Comment: Hi @Henry - thank you for your response.  Unfortunately the full tree resolution is required (data at root, and n-depth leaf nodes).  The root cause to my mind is indeed the granularity and size of the dataset which is entirely relational (it's a taxonomy), and has been decomposed to allow for atomic reference.   We have experienced the infinite recursion problem you mentioned with this, when a circular reference was erroneously injected - a hard limit can help here, but ultimately a lot of recusion is needed to resolve to the level needed.

Comment: I don't know if you suffer from the duplicate subtree problem, if that's the case, the solution is to construct a DAG instead of a tree. Otherwise, recursion is an optimal fit for problems that are recursive in nature (like this one). Another approach would be to do the expansion only on-demand. This is useful if the following stages do not need the full tree but just a few branches (that are unknown in advance).